Azure Functions Payload Size Limit
I have a .NET 8 isolated Azure functions project. I do have a HTTP triggered function that should receive some document content as payload. Initially, I was getting 413 Entity Too Large every time I post payload larger than 28MB. Due to that I changed the configuration in my Program.cs to the following:
_ = services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(opt => opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 524288000);

This worked perfectly until I deployed my function to Azure. Function app is deployed on premium plan (P1v3) on Windows OS. What happens in Azure is that I can not pass payload above 200 MB, despite the configuration above. Every time I go over I got 413 Entity Too Large. Changing configuration to something under 200MB is correctly picked up and limitations are set but it looks like there is hard limit on the payload size.
I also tried setting the MaxRequestBodySize to null, which should result to unlimited payload size (based on the documentation). Since this did not work I tried decorating the function with [DisableRequestSizeLimit] but no luck.
This is my Program.cs:
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
     .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
     {
         IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
         _ = config.AddConfiguration(configuration);
     })
     .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
     {
         _ = services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(opt => opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = builder.Configuration.GetValue<long>("FUNCTIONS_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE_LIMIT"));
     })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

Update 12/11/2024
After further digging I was able to find the below web.config file within the azure-functions-host repo.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/web.config
<requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" maxUrl="8192" maxAllowedContentLength="210000000"/>

From what I see the maxAllowedContentLength is set to 210000000 (200.27MB). From what I know if web.config is deployed as part of the function app it will be ignored. Is this still the case? Is there any other workaround or my only option is to change the approach to use blobs for example (chunking won't do the trick for me)?

Provide your function code @Vasil.

You don't need the function code since it never got to the point of hitting the function.

I will check from my end if it works.

Any updates @PravallikaKV?

Have to updated Functions_Request_Body_Size_Limit in App settings of azure function app for this ? However in same documentation maximum request size is mentioned as 104,857,600 bytes

It's updated. In my code sample this is the variable used to set the Kestrel server limit

For Http Requests, the limit is 100MB as per docs, however you can process files with 800MB size using InputStream approach

This is the approach I took initially but I sill get the error above.

The only way possible is using Blob trigger

@VasilIndzhev, check if the below provided answer helps.

As mentioned in the comments and MSDOC, Http Trigger function has limit of 100MB size for http requests.
However, you can process large files like 800MB using InputStream approach, refer the solutions here.
The other approach to achieve the same is using custom container, overwrite the web.config with Dockerfile as mentioned in GitHub issue1 & issue2.  Need to rebuild the container and deploy every time.
The better approach to achieve your requirement is to use blob storage for managing files of large size.
I have created a Blob Trigger Azure function and able to trigger the function by uploading a file of 200MB size to the Storage container.
[Function(nameof(Function))]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples/{name}", Connection = "demo")] Stream stream, string name)
{
    using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
}

Uploaded file in the container:

Console Output:
Functions:

        Function: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-12T12:15:25.998Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-12T12:21:02.103Z] Executing 'Functions.Function' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): samples-workitems/sample_payload.txt', Id=137a93d7-963b-48e7-93bd-e36b7683d741)
[2024-11-12T12:21:02.111Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 33d4a36c-0cc8-44b9-ae7c-3cb08758bc30, DequeueCount: 2, InsertedOn: 2024-11-12T12:10:51.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-11-12T12:10:44.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-11-12T12:10:44.000+00:00
[2024-11-12T12:22:46.043Z] Executing 'Functions.Function' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): samples/sample_payload.txt', Id=74de2755-2aeb-4b43-8011-69b23c94fe78)
[2024-11-12T12:22:46.047Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 71e3c673-a9bc-4d62-a934-08dec80e2589, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-11-12T12:22:45.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-11-12T12:22:38.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-11-12T12:22:38.000+00:00

Portal:

